# (Major) editing bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment, editing

This happened a few minutes ago. When I was editing a comment, the phrase `[object Object]` came up, and after I write something next to it, say `hello`, then it literally comes out to be `[object Object] hello`.

Something wrong with the editing system?

Comment: [object Object] demonstration

Comment: Same for me. ${}{}$

Comment: This seems to be network-wide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314305/274942.

Comment: [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314309), editing comments should work again soon. [Like, it already does :D]